# How to reuse a form in asp.net core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got number of places where I need to use an address in my app so I tried to make this DRY and create an address partial view like this:

```
@model AddressEditViewModel

<div class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="Address1" class="form-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Address1" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Address1" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="Address2" class="form-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Address2" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Address2" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="City" class="form-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label asp-for="USStateID" class="form-label"></label>
        <select asp-items="@Model.USStates" asp-for="USStateID" class="form-select"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="USStateID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        <label asp-for="Zip" class="form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Zip" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Zip" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I had no luck when I put it into another page with the partial tag helper:

```
<partial name="_Address" model="Model.Address" />
```

Now I understand why this technique doesn't work - that partial views are just for making HTML and don't get processed by the model binder on the way back.

But I would prefer not to copy and paste forms all over my site. Is there any better way to reuse commonly used form bits like this?

Comment: _"Now I understand why this technique doesn't work"_ - using `<partial>` for reusable HTML blocks in `<form>` elements with model-binding works fine for me - something is going wrong in your project - but you haven't told us what the actual problem is...

Comment: Try: `<partial name="_Address" model="@Model.Address" />` - note the `@`. Of course `Model.Address` must be of type `AddressEditViewModel`.

Comment: Did you put the partial view in the folder /Views/Shared ?

Comment: The form is rendered perfectly well out on the final page, but when the form is submitted back there values are not bound back to the ViewModel in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", customViewData)

You can find more details in here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-data-from-partial-views

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the type of `Model.Address` is `AddressEditViewModel`.And make sure the partial view is in the right folder so that you can call it.

Model:

```
public class TestModel {

        public AddressEditViewModel Address { get; set; }
    }
public class AddressEditViewModel {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int USStateID { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> USStates { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult B()
        {

            return View(new TestModel {Address=new AddressEditViewModel {  Address1="d1",Address2="d2", City="C", USStates=new List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> { }, Zip="111"} });


        }
```

_Address.cshtml path:

```
Views/Shared/_Address.cshtml
```

B.cshtml:

```
@model TestModel 
<partial name="_Address" model="Model.Address" />
```

result:
[image]